# Projectors, White Boards & Electronic devices in judicial courts

Tags: evidence, us-supreme-court, rules-of-court, uk-supreme-court

Are projectors, white boards and other electronic devices viz monitor screens, laptops,scanners, recording and playback devices etc. available or allowed in courts?

As a example, the lawyer of either the plaintiff or defendant would like to present using a projector and display screen clipings, transcripts, laptop etc. as part of evidences, proofs.

Is this allowed in the high courts and Supreme Courts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These questions are typically left to the discretion of the judge in whose courtroom the presentation is happening.

It is very common to see these types of devices in trial courts, but they are much less common in appellate courts, and I doubt you'd ever see one in the United States Supreme Court, where the arguments are essentially limited to oral presentations.

Comment: Usually there is or can be a pretrial conference prior to a trial at which the judges and lawyers discuss logistical practicalities about how many minutes parties get for opening and closing arguments, how many copies of exhibits are needed when, and AV issues for courtroom presentations, who sits where when there are multiple parties, etc., at which these issues are presented to the judge so the judge can decide.